# Resizable arrays in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, arrays, reporting-services, dynamic-arrays

I am writing custom code in my report and in it I need a re sizable integer array.

Heres the code

`Dim users() As Integer

ReDim Preserve users(0 To UBound(users) + 1) As Integer`

When I try to run the report, it says 
`'redim' statements can no longer be used to declare array variables`

How do I get around this one? VB is kind of far thing for me, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: No thats not going to work, might help a bit if you put what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know VB had ArrayList with it. It solves my problem.